# Python threading and locks

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, pyspin

I have some code which looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

""" test out threading with PySpin and matplotlib """

import datetime
import threading
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import PySpin

__LOCK = threading.Lock()

# Set up figure
__FIG = plt.figure()
__AXES = __FIG.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

# Get camera
__SYSTEM = PySpin.System.GetInstance()
__CAM = __SYSTEM.GetCameras().GetByIndex(0)

def test():
    """ test thread for streaming image """

    while True:
        with __LOCK:
            print('test thread: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            image = get_image() # pylint: disable=unused-variable

def get_image():
    """ grabs image and returns numpy array """

    image = __CAM.GetNextImage()

    # Initialize image data
    image_data = None

    # Ensure image is complete
    if not image.IsIncomplete():
        # Get image data
        image_data = image.GetNDArray()

        # Release image
        image.Release()

    return image_data

def main():
    """ test """

    # Start Acquisition
    __CAM.Init()
    __CAM.BeginAcquisition()

    # Start thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=test)
    thread.start()

    # Update plot
    while True:
        #import time
        #time.sleep(0.01)
        with __LOCK:
            print('primary thread: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            plt.pause(0.01)

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Unfortunately when I run it, I get an output like this:

```
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.297240
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.325118
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.352918
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.381198
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.408484
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.436476
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.463705
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.492506
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.520737
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.548624
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.577559
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.604856
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.633234
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.660484
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.661107
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.661617
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.662168
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.662787
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.663385
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.664000
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.664629
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.665230
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.665864
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.666540
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.669028
test thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.676831
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.683702
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.711935
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.739462
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.767674
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.795136
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.822378
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.849625
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.877958
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.905631
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.932940
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.960137
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:49.987946
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:50.015238
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:50.042956
primary thread: 2018-04-30 21:21:50.070503
```

What I don't understand is why is it "stuck" on one thread for a long time before it switches over to the other thread? I figured while one thread has the lock, the other would be waiting, and would acquired it when the other thread released it, but that doesn't seem to be the case here...

Comment: [GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) :-(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ So I dont want to sound too negative here, but whats the point of having the threading library with locks in python if this sort of stuff happens? It almost seems useless.

Comment: They're working on getting rid of it in the forthcoming python versions, actually.

Comment: Because threading is still useful for IO-bound concurrency.  That's very different from "useless" - you need to know the right tools for the job.

Comment: This seems really dumb but I think I've found a "solution" by placing a short pause **after** the mutex gets released. This may allow other threads a chance to acquire the lock.

Comment: @Justin: It’s fine to ask a question about the behavior you observe, but why is it a **problem** that the threads do not alternate?